# Unix shell not displaying UTF8 line drawing symbols

Tags: shell, unix, utf-8

Fist, somewhat irrelevant background of the problem:

So I wrote [an advanced variable dumper](https://github.com/raveren/kint/) for PHP that now detects when the script is launched in CLI and adds some eye candy if the client supports it (putty screenshot):

[image: putty Kint screenshot]

The colors are pretty, but I'm more interested in the formatting now. I'm using the following seven UTF8 symbols to achieve this:

```
    ┌ ─ ┐
    │
    └ ▄ ┘
```

However, on a **different computer** launching the same script **via the same SSH connection credentials** outputs this mess:

```
ââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
â                                      $t                                      â
ââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
array (1) [
    integer 123
]
â
 â
  â
   â
    â
     â
      â
       â
        â
         â
          â
           â
            â
             â
              â
               â
                â
                 â
                  â
                   â
                    â
                     â
                      â
                       â
                        â
                         â
                          â
                           â
                            â
                             â
                              â
                               â
                                â
                                 â
                                  â
                                   â
                                    â
                                     â
                                      â
                                       â
                                        â
                                         â
                                          â
                                           â
                                            â
                                             â
                                              â
                                               â
                                                â
                                                 â
                                                  â
                                                   â
                                                    â
                                                     â
                                                      â
                                                       â
                                                        â
                                                         â
                                                          â
                                                           â
                                                            â
                                                             â
                                                              â
                                                               â
                                                                â
                                                                 â
                                                                  â
                                                                   â
                                                                    â
                                                                     â
                                                                      â
                                                                       â
                                                                        â
                                                                         â
                                                                          â
                                                                           â
                                                                            â
                                                                             â
                                                                              â
                                                                               â

Called from APP/shell/cron/test.php:8
```

I'm a total unix noob and not sure how much more debugging information would be useful, but the correct display is on WIN8.1 and the wrong one is on WIN7. Also, in putty:

```
uname -a
Linux [removed] 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 9 21:36:05 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What can cause this? Is there a workaround or maybe I can detect UTF8 support via a shell command (to fallback to ASCII symbols in that case)?

I'd appreciate any input, any idea I could try - I'd hate to revert to always formatting with the limited ASCII set.

---

### EDIT with solution

The displayed characters are dependent on client-side putty settings as demonstrated [here](https://serverfault.com/q/475925/129806). So since midnight commander can afford some artifacts when used with misconfigured clients, so can I. The only change I did was replace the `▄` character with `═` so it doesn't cause new lines like in the snippet above. The fixed output looks like this (first one's with correct, utf-8 language settings):

[image]

Comment: Are you using putty to ssh then ?

Comment: yup, I'm using http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/ which is a multi-tabbed putty wrapper on both machines to connect to ssh

Comment: Okay,go in the settings -> translation. Change the language from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)`.

Comment: ok, thanks! I can now replicate the issue on both computers. I'm guessing there's no way to find out the language on the client side..? And no way to force other language either?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/475925/how-to-fix-putty-showing-garbled-characters

Comment: You could use `locale` to check which language it is using, although this isn't foolproof.

Comment: @Jidder: Why do you say that?

Comment: @Jidder, the problem is client-side, so there's no way for me to check the proper display, I'll edit my question with the solution I came up with

Comment: @AaronDigulla Say what ? And raveren could you not have the script check at the start ?

Comment: the script has no access to client side, the locale command is useful, but it only affects what is sent from server, the fault lies in putty - misconfiguring its executable results in the undesired output. Thanks a lot for your help, you are the one that led me to the solution, I'm just sorry I can't grant you any reputation for the input :(

Comment: @Raveren No worries, glad you found a fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]** This question on serverfault should help: https://serverfault.com/questions/475925/how-to-fix-putty-showing-garbled-characters

I have no idea why Windows 8.1 works differently than Windows 7. My first guess for problems like this one is that the encoding was messed with but since you use the same command on both Windows machines, it should either fail on both or none.

The next culprit is usually the font but then, you would get a hollow box instead of an `â` for unknown symbols.

The next thing that I'd try is a workaround. Instead of formatting on the Unix side, I'd create a server script which just sends me the variables and their values in an internal format (CSV, XML, JSON, ...). Then I'd write a script to query those values and format them locally. That way, the formatter could examine the local system, determine its capabilities and do the right thing.

Comment: thanks for the input (and the edit), but none of these are viable solutions, sorry

Comment: yeah, I already found it on my own, and in the end I resorted to using `═` as the lower symbol and it looks decently now even when utf8 is not supported http://i.imgur.com/UPmSEgS.png

Comment: @Raveren: If you found a correct/better solution, please post it here (or on serverfault) so other people can find it. My answer just pointed you in the right direction :-)